# How can i get all get substring from a complex string using regex or any other solution?

Tags: javascript, swift, regex, regex-group

Input should be like this:

```
class1{name=‘adam.smith’}.class2{name=‘john’}.subjectMath
```

Output something like:

```
["class1{name='adam.smith'}", "class2{name='john'}", "subjectMath"]
```

Any solution?

Comment: Why is this tagged with multiple languages?

Comment: Do you have any control over the input? If you do, I would strongly recommend you switch to some kind of standardized serialization (YAML, JSON, XML, CSV, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `split`:

```js
var input = "class1{name=‘adam.smith’}.class2{name=‘john’}.subjectMath";
var parts = input.split(/\.(?![^{]*’)/);
console.log(parts);
```

The regex used for the split requires some explanation:

```
\.          match a literal dot
(?![^{]*’)  but assert that we DON'T encounter a text curly quote
            looking forward so long as we don't hit a { first
```

The negative lookahead fails the dot in `adam.smith`, because we can find a curly quote without encountering a `{` opening bracket, which would imply that the dot is not a connecting dot.

Comment: It doesn't work, it actually split the name since there is a dot in there too

Comment: @MickaelB. I fixed it.  Sorry, I didn't realize your data could have dots in it.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a sting like this:

```
string = "class1{name=‘adam.smith’}.class2{name=‘john’}.subjectMath";
```

You could try with this:

```
string.split(/(?<=})./)
```

which will return:

```
[ "class1{name=‘adam.smith’}" , "class2{name=‘john’}" , "subjectMath" ]
```

Comment: Not all versions of JavaScript support lookbehinds.

Comment: Yes, of course, I was assuming it does support.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.1

This is a solution for Swift assuming that the input structure remains the same, with the bracket preceding the dot :

```swift
var input = "class1{name=‘adam.smith’}.class2{name=‘john’}.subjectMath"

func splittingClasses(_ input: String) -> [String] {
    var total: [String] = []
    var parts = input.components(separatedBy: "}.")
    let endpart =  "}"
    for i in 0 ..< parts.count {
        if i == parts.count - 1 {
            total.append(parts[i])
        } else {
            total.append(parts[i] + endpart)
        }
    }
    print(total)
    return total
}
splittingClasses(input) 
// returns ["class1{name=‘adam.smith’}", "class2{name=‘john’}", "subjectMath"]
```

Comment: `input.components(separatedBy: "}.").joined(separator: "}")`

Answer (score 0):

You could match everything that is not an `.` of course this gives some issues with the `.` within `‘...’` context. For this reason we should also match those.

```js
const input = "class1{name=‘adam.smith’}.class2{name=‘john’}.subjectMath";
const output = input.match(/(?:‘[^’]*’|[^.])+/g);

console.log(output);
```

```
‘[^’]*’
```

Will match any `‘` and keeps matching until it finds the closing `’` character, matching anything in-between.

```
[^.]
```

Will match anything that is not a `.` character.